# Auto-Update of a running app doesn't work

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android app which runs unattended on a tablet running Android 6.
I've uploaded an alpha version to Google Play and install it on an Android tablet.
I've remain logged-in to the Google Play on the tablet and auto-update is turned on.

Yet, my app is running now for 2 days since I've pushed an update to the app and the app still did not update.

If I open Google Play on the tablet I see the new version.

Is there anything else I need to do to have the app update automatically without use open Google Play and press Update?

Comment: When I open Google Play I see an item say `Updates Pending (1)` with sub-title `Auto-update is turned on` and beneath it list my app with an Update button.

Comment: I've event setup auto off and on in the settings and after the restart the app still didn't auto-update

Answer (score 1):

Apps restart when they get updated. Because of this, Google Play tries to avoid auto-upating apps when they are running in the foreground as this is a bad user experience, the app restarting while the user is using it. This is one possible reason.

Another reason is Google Play by default only updates apps when the device is plugged into power and connected to wi-fi, to avoid draining the battery and using up the user's mobile data. This could be another reason.

However, if the app is not in the foreground and the tablet is plugged into power and on wi-fi, and autoupdate is turned on it should update within 24 hours. If it doesn't this is probably a bug. You should take a bug report and contact Google Developer support using the Google Play console.

Comment: The tablet is always connected to power and WiFi. Also the app is always running. Is there any way to force update using api?

Comment: No, there isn't right now. I'll see if I can find out what happens in such a situation

Comment: ok, I'll try to close my app so it will have time to auto-update and have the device restart automatically sometime later.

Comment: It might just be update takes a bit longer. I'll ask our update team.

Comment: I can allow the app even an hour, there is no time pressure.

Comment: Can you tell us your use case (why the app is always foreground?). Just curious.

Comment: Of course. It’s a digital picture frame so the tablet is dedicated for it and always runs the app. I have setup auto off at 22:00 and auto on at 6:30 so I’ll try quit the app at 21:00 leaving an hour for update.